# Getting the device phone number using ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using cordova sim plugin to get the device phonenumber, but i am getting the following error message saying:

> THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Sim.get Sim Info blocked the main
>   thread for 35ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool()

After that SIM Info is coming null.

**Could any one suggest the best approach to get the phone number?**

Comment: Have you tried by using it but from [ionic-native](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sim/)?